# hide default post body field in backend

Tags: admin, post-type-support

Is there a easy non-css-hacking way to hide the default post body field in the dashboard?

I simply want to have the title field and some adv. custom fields but remove the default post body field.

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support()
{
   $post_type = 'your post type';
   remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```

Add this to your themes functions.php and it should take care of it. cheers :)